# Consider the function $f(x)= 0$ if $x≤0$ and $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ if $x>0$. Prove that $f$ is infinitely differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Infinitely differentiable function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119858/infinitely-differentiable-function)

Consider the function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by

$f(x)= \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $x \le 0$} \\ e^{-1/x^2} & \text{if $x > 0$} \end{cases}$

Prove that $f$ is indefinitely differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, and that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n \ge 1$. Conclude that $f$ does not have a converging power series expansion for $x$ near the origin.

Comment: [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/4700/8271), [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/4757/8271) and [very the same](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/119858/8271)

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** If $P$ is a polynomial and $g(x)=P(\frac1x) e^{-\frac1{x^2}}$, show that $g'(x)=Q(\frac1x) e^{-\frac1{x^2}}$ with a possibly different polynomial $Q$. Conclude that all derivatives of $f$ have this form and show that they all vanish as $x\to 0^+$, thus matching the $0$ from the negative axis.

Answer (score 0):

Idea on how to get started: clearly $f$ is differentiable for all $x\neq 0$, so you need just consider whether $f'(0)$ exists. That is, you need to consider whether the limit
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(0 + h) - f(0) }{h}.
$$
Consider the left-hand and the right-hand limits. Consider for example:
$$
\lim_{h \to 0+} \frac{f(0 + h) - f(0) }{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{h^2}}}{h}.
$$

Can you prove that this limit is equal to the left hand limit?

After you have done this, you know what the derivative is on all $\mathbb{R}$. So you can try to compute the process with a new limit. Hopefully you see a pattern.